# Ember handlebar helper programmatic record property access?

Tags: templates, ember.js, properties, handlebars.js, record

In one case a template will have

```
{{input/number value=record.VolM3}}
```

in another it will have

```
{{input/number value=record.VolBbl}}
```

Is there a way to make it such that the end part of the record attribute is accessed programmatically? i.e.

```
{{input/number value=record.Vol + volUnit}} or
{{input/number value=(concat record.Vol + volUnit)}}
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Hi @Mike R, does your `volUnit` defined in your controller or component?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so :

```
{{input type="number" value=(get record (concat "Vol" "M3"))}}
{{input type="number" value=(get record (concat "Vol" "Bbl"))}}
```

I tested it with dummy `record`.

```
record = {VolM3: "100", VolBbl: "101"}
```

Here i have created a gist with
[Working Example](https://ember-twiddle.com/4def0b7ead60d5858944f407a391d348?openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2Chttps://ember-twiddle.com/4def0b7ead60d5858944f407a391d348?openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2C)

Comment: while the actual way you get the value is 100% right it is important to notice that `{{input type="number` and `{{input/number` is *not* the same. The first is the ember internal `input` component and the second a component at `components/input/number.hbs`

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
{{input/number value=(get record (concat "Vol" volUnit))}}
```

or in modern ember:

```
<Input::Number @value={{get record (concat "Vol" volUnit)}} />
```

Comment: If I got it right from the title of the question `{{input/number}}` is a helper not a component. So `<Input::Number>` would be wrong even in modern ember.

Comment: actually I wouldnt be so sure here. Historically `{{input` has been named a *helper*. Even in ember 3.0 the docs reference "*The `{{input}}` helper*", so I assume its just a confusion about the terms component and helper.